# How to make the app use the whole screen height (remove the Toolbar) in Codename One?

Tags: toolbar, codenameone

I don't want my app to display the toolbar on the upper part of the screen. I tried to `setGlobalToolbar(false)` in the `init()` method (or set the globalToolbarBool constant to false in the theme)  but the toolbar still appears in the forms (tested on the simulator => see picture).

[image]

I also tried to let the `setGlobalToolbar(true)` and hide it in the beforeShow methods with `f.getToolbar().hideToolbar()` but the arrow  still appears on the top left corner (see picture below)  until I touch the screen.

[image: after hiding the toolbar]

Actually how can I get rid of the toolbar (ie the area circled in red on the picture) ?

Any help appreciated,

Cheers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I finally got it right as I wanted. To get rid of the toolbar, you have to `setGlobalToolbar(false)` in the `init()` method (or set the `globalToolbarBool` constant to `false` in the theme [in the Designer]).

So now there is no toolbar but it is replaced by a side menu, as I described in my original post.

To make the side menu also disappear, you have also to set `HideLeftSideMenuBool` constant to `true` in the theme (open your theme.res file in the Designer).

Eventually the picture can take the whole height. So problem solved!

Answer (score 2):

If i relay correctly, setting the title to an empty String or removing an UUID like Title, Toolbar or Statusbar did remove that for me?

It could also be that i turned off nativeNavigation

Comment: Thanks @kaya. I did not try to turn off nativeNavigation because I could not find it, but I set HideLeftMenuBool to true **AND** setGlobalToolbar(false) (see my answer below). Both settings were needed in my case.

Comment: If commands are added it can force the Toolbar to appear. You can also use `removeAllCommands()` which should work too. There is also `hideToolbar()` which should allow you to fold/show the toolbar.

Comment: @Shai : I noticed that if I `hideToolbar()` the arrow still appears! I did not test  but maybe I **also** need to `removeAllCommands()`. Anyway thanks!